# Trait Object is not Object-safe error

Tags: rust

The following code does not compile for me.

```rust
trait A {
    fn fun0(&self);
    fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<Self>>;
}

struct B0 {
    id: usize,
}

impl A for B0 {
    fn fun0(&self) { println!("Value: {:?}", self.id); }
    fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<Self>> { Option::None }
}

struct B1 {
    id: isize,
}

impl A for B1 {
    fn fun0(&self) { println!("Value: {:?}", self.id); }
    fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<Self>> { Option::Some(Box::new(B1 { id: self.id, })) }
}

enum C {
    None,
    Put { object: Box<A>, },
}

fn fun1(values: Vec<C>) {
    for it in values.iter() {
        match *it {
            C::Put { object: ref val, } => val.fun0(),
            C::None => (),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let obj_b0 = Box::new(B0 { id: 778, });
    let obj_b1 = Box::new(B1 { id: -8778, });
    let obj_c0 = C::Put { object: obj_b0, };
    let obj_c1 = C::Put { object: obj_b1, };
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(obj_c0);
    vec.push(obj_c1);
    fun1(vec);
}
```

gives an error:

```
cargo run
   Compiling misc v0.0.1 (file:///home/spandan/virtualization/coding/my/rust-tests/misc/misc)
src/main.rs:188:48: 188:54 error: the trait `A` is not implemented for the type `A` [E0277]
src/main.rs:188             C::Put { object: ref val, } => val.fun0(),
                                                               ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:197:35: 197:41 error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `A` is not object-safe [E0038]
src/main.rs:197     let obj_c0 = C::Put { object: obj_b0, };
                                                  ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:197:35: 197:41 note: method `fun2` references the `Self` type in its arguments or return type
src/main.rs:197     let obj_c0 = C::Put { object: obj_b0, };
                                                  ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:198:35: 198:41 error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `A` is not object-safe [E0038]
src/main.rs:198     let obj_c1 = C::Put { object: obj_b1, };
                                                  ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:198:35: 198:41 note: method `fun2` references the `Self` type in its arguments or return type
src/main.rs:198     let obj_c1 = C::Put { object: obj_b1, };
                                                  ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
Could not compile `misc`.
```

working with

```
rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (00978a987 2015-04-18) (built 2015-04-19)
```

The problem appears when `fun2(&self)` is brought into the picture. It compiles and runs fine if `fun0` is the only existing function in the trait. But my code needs such a pattern - How do i do it ?

**Edit:** the correct answer for the above has been given here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985438/1060004) . But i am running into the same problem if i remove the `&self` from function signature (ie., make it static):

```
fn fun2() -> Option<Box<A>>
```

what is the issue now ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have noticed, the problem vanishes when you remove `fun2` method. Let's look at it more closely:

```
fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<Self>>;
```

Note that its output type contains `Self`, that is, the type which the trait is implemented for. For example, if `A` is implemented for `String`, it would be `String`:

```
impl A for String {
    fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<String>> { ... }
}
```

However! With the trait objects the actual type of the value is erased, and the only thing that we know about trait objects is that it is a value which implements the trait, but we don't know the *actual type* the trait is implemented for. Trait object methods are dispatched dynamically, so the program selects the actual method to call at runtime. These methods have to behave identically, that is, accept the same number of parameters of the same size (pairwise) and return values of the same size too. If a method uses `Self` somewhere in its signature, like `fun2`, its implementations won't be compatible with each other because they would need to operate on values of different size, and hence such methods can't be unified.

Such methods (which can't work with trait objects) are called object-unsafe (or not object-safe). If a trait contains such methods, it can't be made a trait object - it is also called not object-safe.

What would work, I believe, is that you can make the trait return a trait object:

```
fn fun2(&self) -> Option<Box<A>>
```

Now the dependency on the actual type is lifted, and the trait becomes object-safe again.

Comment: 15 seconds.  You utter ratbag.  :D

Comment: Yeah, it always happens with me too :)

Comment: brilliant as always ! I's trying to equate Box to `std::unique_ptr<A>`  where `A` is some Base class. That is what i though Box<Self> did and implicit casting (to base) would occur if concrete type was given. But seems Box<A> and Box<Self> are different notions. Still wrapping my head round rust :)

Comment: Yes, there is (almost) no subtyping in Rust, so `Box<Self>` is never `Box<A>`. You have to be explicit :)

Comment: ok one more question: if the method signature is `fn fun2() -> Option<Box<A>>` then it is still the same error. Why? Why does static function not work?

Comment: @ustulation, since trait object methods are dispatched dynamically, they need their object to obtain a pointer to a virtual table. With static methods there is no object to dispatch on, so static methods can't be called through an object and are not present in the vtable. Hence they are not object-safe too.

Comment: But the v-table should be present when assigning a derived pointer to the Base (traits in rust) pointer in the return type, no?

Comment: Do you mean the return type of the static method? But when you call it there is no object yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message pretty much spells out the immediate problem: you're trying to use a non-object-safe trait in an object context, and you can't do that.

You can remove `fun2` from the trait `A`, and define it in a different trait: its presence will prevent `A` from ever being used as a "trait object"; so `&A`, `Box<A>`, etc. will all out of the question.  Each type can then implement both of these traits.

Another alternative is to change `fun2` so that its result *does not* contain the `Self` type; your example is too abstract to know, but would `Option<Box<A>>` be acceptable?

As for *why*: in order for a trait to be used as a trait object, the compiler has to be able to generate a vtable for the trait's methods so that it can do dynamic, runtime dispatch.  This means that every method in the trait has to be implementable with the same types (the `self` parameter is a special case).  So what does `fun2` return?  It has to return an `Option<Box<Self>>`, but `Self` is a different type for every implementation!  There's no possible way to unify it!