# How to specify that all implementers of a trait must also implement Serialize?

Tags: rust, serde

I am curious to see how much boilerplate one can save through built-in reflection.

### A little background

My idea behind structured logging is to use various small tailored types to separate content from representation. Instead of unstructured `logger.info("Found a bar with {} foos", bar.foo)` one uses something like `logger.info(FoundBar{ _bar: bar })`

### My Rust-ish approach

- define a `Log` trait
- provide a default implementation that calls the Serde machinery to serialize the type (to JSON in this example)
- define loggable types easily by letting them "inherit" the default implementation
- profit

Define the trait, providing a default impl:

```
trait Log {
    fn to_log(&self) -> String {
        serde_json::to_string(&self).unwrap()
    }
}
```

(RLS is already drawing angry red squiggles, but bear with me)

Define a simple type to be logged:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Message {
    msg: String,
}
```

and let it use the default implementation:

```
impl Log for Message {}
```

and finally the polymorphic logging function defined in terms of the trait:

```
fn log(log: &Log) {
    println!("serialized = {}", log.to_log());
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
 --> src\main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         serde_json::to_string(&self).unwrap()
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `Self`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` for `&Self`
  = note: required by `serde_json::ser::to_string`
```

Adding the `where Self` suggestion to my trait function only produces different errors (`error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message`), but apart from that it seems like a Bad Idea(TM) to have this implementation detail of Serde leak into my code.

How do I portably constrain my trait (using `where`?) to only apply to types that have the correct derive? Even better, can I "inject" the derive functionality into types using the trait?

Comment: @Shepmaster good remark: in hindsight the question should have been "[...] to implement serde::Serialize", which amounts to half an answer already...

Comment: I was hoping that was what you meant. I don't see any harm in having a more accurate title to catch future searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of [your problem on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=90c020a162197f66f2803f6b8a1ef07c), you get a more accurate error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         serde_json::to_string(&self).unwrap()
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `Self`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: serde::Serialize` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `&Self`
  = note: required by `serde_json::ser::to_string`
```

Following the suggestion, but using the idiomatic supertrait syntax, answers your question:

```
trait Log: serde::Serialize {
    fn to_log(&self) -> String {
        serde_json::to_string(&self).unwrap()
    }
}
```

---

You'll need to change your log function for object-safety reasons:

```
fn log(log: &impl Log) {
    println!("serialized = {}", log.to_log());
}
```

See also:

- [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45116984/155423)
- [Unable to create a polymorphic type because the trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39412626/155423)
- [How to implement `serde::Serialize` for a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50021897/155423)
- [How can deserialization of polymorphic trait objects be added in Rust if at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/155423)

Comment: How come the playground error message is clearer? Newer (unstable?) version of Rust/compiler? I am on stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc, which uses rustc 1.30.1

Comment: @dlw I assume it's the *minimal* aspect. The playground is also using 1.30.1 (at the moment), but this example only has two crates in use.

Comment: Could you expand on the "object-safety reasons"? Why would I want to borrow from the unnamed object instead of passing ownership to `log()`? [unnamed object resulting from calls like `logger.info(FoundBar{ _bar: bar })`]

Comment: @dlw *Could you expand on* — that's what all 4 of the linked Q&A are about; I didn't want to further duplicate existing information. *Why would I want to borrow* — that's up to you. Your original code took a reference trait object (`&Log`), so switching to a reference to a generic type was the smallest change. You could also pick `impl Log`.

Answer (score 1):

Using trait inheritance works, but using the right Serde trait, not the compiler-suggested one:

```
trait Log: serde::Serialize {
    fn to_log(&self) -> String {
        serde_json::to_string(&self).unwrap()
    }
}
```