# Vector of polymorphic structs with an associated type in trait

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I am trying to understand how **polymorphism** works when using a **trait with an associated type**. Consider the following trait:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn talk (&self);
}
```

This trait is used by the following structures:

```rust
struct Dog;
struct Cow;

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn talk (&self) {
        println!("Woof");
    }
}

impl Animal for Cow {
    fn talk (&self) {
        println!("Moo");
    }
}
```

Then I loop over a `Vec<&Animal>`, and polymorphism works well here:

```rust
fn main() {
    let animals: Vec<&Animal> = vec![&Dog, &Cow];
    for animal in &animals {
        animal.talk();
    }
}
// output:
// Woof
// Moo
```

So far so good. Now, I **add an associated type** `Food` to the trait (the type is not used, but it is only for the minimal repro).

```rust
struct Meat;
struct Herb;

trait Animal {
    type Food;
    ...
}
impl Animal for Dog {
    type Food = Meat;
    ...
}
impl Animal for Cow {
    type Food = Herb;
    ...
}
```

And now I get the error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Food` (from trait `Animal`) must be specified
   --> src/main.rs:188:23
163 |     type Food;
    |     ---------- `Food` defined here
...
188 |     let animals: Vec<&Animal> = vec![&Dog, &Cow];
    |                       ^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `Animal<Food = Type>`
```

But in this case, I cannot just follow the error message since the number of `struct`s implementing the trait `Animal` is not supposed to be static.

What is the Rust way to solve that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You’re probably after an `enum Food { Meat, Herb }` with a `fn food(&self) -> Food` in your trait.

Comment: I am still learning Rust but I don't think I can change `Meat` and `Herb` into enums here. This is a minimal repro, in reality these are very complex structs. My question was not about adapting the code, but more about using polymorphic vectors in rust with associated types in general. But maybe I misunderstood your answer

Comment: The only reason for preferring trait objects over enums is where you're writing a library whose downstream users may create implementations about which you cannot know in advance—but it comes at the cost of both runtime performance and "object safety", imposing additional restrictions that include specifying concrete values for any associated types.

Comment: Thank you. I am probably misleading about the power of rust enums, but here the part of code that make the polymorphic call is not aware of the different types of animals. How can I use a `match` pattern without knowing the different types, to use the right function ? That's not so much about users, I just don't wan't to copy/paste the entire list of types everywhere everytime I add or remove a type

Comment: If you're only interested in a single variant, consider `if let`.  Otherwise you can have a `match` with a catchall wildcard `_` pattern to ignore variants you don't care about.

Comment: My main code is a concrete example. In `main`, I don't want to copy/paste in an `match` pattern every types that implements the trait, that is precisely why polymorphism is useful in general.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the animal's food in `main` though?  Perhaps you should implement a method on `Food` instead?

Comment: I don't think `Food` features are in the scope of this problem, the problem is: polymorphism works well, I have a `main` function when I can call the subtype `talk()` function without copy/pasting the 1435 animal type names. But if the trait has an associated type (that is not something I can change), it does not work anymore. I'd like to keep this `anything.talk()` that called the right subtype function that worked in the first time. I would be surprised there is no way to do that

Comment: No, `Food` is indeed the problem here. Also, you never actually had polymorphism in the first place, because `Animal`, or, rather `dyn Animal`, as compiler should tell you, is a definite, concrete type. When you added an associated type to it, it instead become an infinite set of `dyn Animal<Food = T>` types.

Comment: Trait objects without an explicit `dyn` is still working with my version. But thank you to remind me this will be deprecated. However the problem is still the same, I can't remove the associated type, and I'd like to have a unique `anything.talk()`. So if I understand well, you are saying me it is basically not possible in Rust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&Animal` [is short for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650070/what-does-dyn-mean-in-a-type) `&dyn Animal`. `dyn Animal` is a *trait object* type, and it only exists for a given trait if the trait is [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects). Traits with associated types are not object-safe, because `dyn Animal` cannot implement `Animal` without specifying the associated type `Food`.¹

This is an inherent limitation of runtime polymorphism (trait objects): you don't know the concrete type, so you can't know its associated type.²

If you want to create a vector of things you can call `.talk()` on, it's easy enough to create a trait just for that ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66fb9a7792c78f116ed3312ac8672d0a)):

```
trait Talk {
    fn talk(&self);
}

impl<A: Animal> Talk for A {
    fn talk(&self) {
        Animal::talk(self);
    }
}

let animals: Vec<&dyn Talk> = vec![&Dog, &Cow];
```

You won't be able to write any code that uses `Food` via a `&dyn Talk`, which is the point: `Food` is dependent on the concrete type, and your vector contains multiple concrete types.

### See also

- [Why does a generic method inside a trait require trait object to be sized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42620022/3650362)
- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/3650362)
- [Unable to create a polymorphic type because the trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39412626/3650362)

---

¹ You *can* make a trait object of types that all have *the same* associated types, like `dyn Animal<Food = Herb>`. This is commonly seen with `Iterator`, as in `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>`. But it does not solve the problem when the `Animal`s have different kinds of `Food`.

² With compile-time polymorphism (generics), you can write code that is generic over anything that implements `Animal` with any `Food` type. But you can't put things of different compile-time types in a `Vec`, so that doesn't help either.