# Combine traits with associated types in rust

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to create a kind of wrapper trait that combines multiples traits and a function that return the associated implementation of the trait. It works well as long as you don't have associated types. I don't know how to refer to the `Output` type
I am aware of how to combine traits :
[Is there a way to combine multiple traits in order to define a new trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983355/is-there-a-way-to-combine-multiple-traits-in-order-to-define-a-new-trait)
[Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits)

But unfortunately, I've not found anything with associated types

Here is a summarized example of where I'm stucked

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

pub trait Hello {
    fn hello(&self);
}
pub trait Goodbye {
    fn goodbye(&self);
}
struct Suffix {
    suffix: String,
}
pub struct World {
    content: String,
}

impl World {
    fn new(content: String) -> Self {
        World { content: content }
    }
}

impl Hello for World {
    fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello {}", self.content)
    }
}
impl Goodbye for World {
    fn goodbye(&self) {
        println!("Goodbye {}", self.content)
    }
}
impl Add<Suffix> for World {
    type Output = World;
    fn add(self, other: Suffix) -> World {
        let suffixed: String = self.content + &other.suffix;
        World::new(suffixed)
    }
}

trait HelloGoodbye: Hello + Goodbye {}
impl<T> HelloGoodbye for T where T: Hello + Goodbye {}

fn get_hello_goodbye() -> Box<dyn HelloGoodbye> {
    Box::new(World::new("Everyone".to_string()))
}

trait SuffixableHello: Hello + Add<Suffix, Output = Self> {}
impl<T> SuffixableHello for T where T: Hello + Add<Suffix, Output = Self> {}

fn get_suffixable_hello() -> Box<dyn SuffixableHello> {
    Box::new(World::new("Everyone".to_string()))
}


fn main() {
    // This works
    let hello_goodbye = get_hello_goodbye();
    hello_goodbye.hello();
    hello_goodbye.goodbye();

    // This does not work
    let suffixable_hello = get_suffixable_hello();
    suffixable_hello.hello()
}
```

I got this compilation error :

```rust
49 | fn get_suffixable_hello() -> Box<dyn SuffixableHello> {
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `SuffixableHello<Output = Type>`
```

What am I supposed to put there ?

What I've try so far :

- Make trait generic

```rust
trait SuffixableHello<T>: Hello + Add<Suffix, Output = T> {}
impl<T, U> SuffixableHello<T> for T where T: Hello + Add<Suffix, Output = Self> {}
```

And I get

```rust
   |
49 | fn get_suffixable_hello() -> Box<dyn SuffixableHello<T>> {
   |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Where am I supposed to add this `T` generic ? Does my fucntion need to be generic ?

- Only add Output to implementation

```rust
trait SuffixableHello: Hello + Add<Suffix> {}
impl<T> SuffixableHello for T where T: Hello + Add<Suffix, Output = T> {}
```

But I get :

```rust
the value of the associated type `Output` (from trait `Add`) must be specified
```

This makes sense since Output is not declared in the trait.

- Replacing `World` by `Self` in the `impl Add<Suffix> for World`

Am I missing something here ?
Thank you

Also, what if we want to return from the `get_suffixable_hello()` one of two `Hello` implementations, let's say `World` and `World2` to cite @cadolphs like in this doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn get_suffixable_hello() -> Box<dyn SuffixableHello<Output=World>> {
    Box::new(World::new("Everyone".to_string()))
}
```

does the trick.

EDIT: Longer explanation. Your first initial compiler error tells you that you can't just return `Box<dyn SuffixableHello>`. That's because having the same trait but with different associated types isn't allowed, because the signatures of associated methods would be different.

So. We need to put a type there. And what should that type be? Well, given that you're explicitly calling `World::new`, there's really only one type that makes sense here, and that's `World`.

In your toy example that makes it of course a bit silly and redundant because there's only one struct that implements all those traits.

If you had another struct, `World2`, you could *not* have it be returned by `get_suffixable_hello` next to `World`, because `World2` would have associated type `Output=World2` and hence
wouldn't match the `Output=World` associated type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. So it's not possible to do a kind of factory pattern like in this doc [https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html) with associated output ? I thought that using generics over either the struct or the function could do the trick.. Because, what if in this example I want to either return World or World2 based on some input parameters of the functions ?

Comment: It _is_ possible, but not if the associated types are different. For example, you can return a `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i32>>`.

The issue here is that the thing you set `Item` to must be a concrete type, it can't be a trait.

Comment: See here, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213532/vector-of-polymorphic-structs-with-an-associated-type-in-trait

Comment: Actually, your question didn't leave me alone and I kept thinking about it. Then I played around some more and that led me to ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74804181/can-i-have-a-collection-over-trait-objects-where-their-associated-types-implemen) question. 

You _can_ have some fancy polymorphism, but only with the right mix of `Box<dyn` and some mild _coercion_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! This compiler error was also stuck in my head, then I also ask this question in the Rust Forum Community (see https://users.rust-lang.org/t/combine-traits-with-associated-types-in-rust-and-use-factory/85871). It seems to be possible also by changing the Output of the implementation to be `Box<dyn Hello>`. I didn't have the time to test all of this. I try as soon as I can these different solutions.