# Can I have a collection over trait objects where their associated types implement a shared trait?

Tags: rust, associated-types, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects

I know that *generally* you can't have something like `Vec<dyn Iterator>>` because of course you need to specify the associated type.

Now, I can have `Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i32>>>` of course.

But what about something like this:

```rust
trait Foo {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bla;
impl Foo for Bla {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main () {
    // this works of course
    let x: Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i32>>> = vec![];
    
    // this can be defined
    let mut y: Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item=Box<dyn Foo>>>> = vec![];
    
    // but how do I use it? these don't work
    let first_it = Box::new(std::iter::repeat(Box::new(Bar{})));
    let second_it = Box::new(std::iter::repeat(Box::new(Bla{})).take(10));
    
    y.push(first_it);
    y.push(second_it);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
expected `std::iter::Repeat<Box<Bar>>` to be an iterator that yields `Box<dyn Foo>`, but it yields `Box<Bar>`
```

So. Obviously then `Box<Bar>`, despite `Bar` implementing `Foo`, is not considered
an acceptable subtype for `Box<dyn Foo>`.

I know Rust doesn't have the same super-high-order associated types that some other languages have. Is what I'm trying to do fundamentally impossible or just not supported in Rust?

In my mind, there shouldn't be an *inherent* type issue with using `y`. All the elements it contains will be iterators that yield certain items, all of which will implement the same trait, `Foo`.

Or am I just doing something wrong in *creating* the trait object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a structural incompatibility between `Iterator<Item=Box<Bar>>` and `Iterator<Item=Box<dyn Foo>>`. If you aren't aware, `Box<Bar>` has a different size than `Box<dyn Foo>` (single pointer vs two pointers internally).

You can convert, or rather [*coerce*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions), a `Box<Bar>` into a `Box<dyn Foo>` because `Bar` implements `Foo`. But you cannot pass off a `Iterator<Item=Box<Bar>>` as a `Iterator<Item=Box<dyn Foo>>` because there needs to be a place for that conversion to happen.

So yes, you *can* have such a collection, but you need to use the right trait objects proactively:

```
let mut y: Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item=Box<dyn Foo>>>> = vec![];

let first_it = Box::new(std::iter::repeat(Box::new(Bar{})).map(|b| b as Box<dyn Foo>));
let second_it = Box::new(std::iter::repeat(Box::new(Bla{})).map(|b| b as Box<dyn Foo>).take(10));

y.push(first_it);
y.push(second_it);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Yes, I was trying to hack some "as Box<dyn Foo>" somewhere into the code but the explicit conversion via `map` did not occur to me.

And thanks for pointing out the structural difference. Yeah, the `Box<Bar>` as just the one pointer, and `dyn` needs something extra for the vtable, right?

Comment: @cadolphs correct, any indirection via `dyn Trait` requires an additional vtable pointer so that it can be used dynamically.

Comment: Note that type inference gets it right as long as you tell Rust to cast: `std::iter::repeat(Box::new(Bar{})).map (|x| x as _)` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=19b09d9ea0e0673e83f108e3947ac2c6))