# Best Practices Wrapping Non-Object-Safe Traits

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits

I have a trait `Foo`. This has a method which takes a generic type implementing `Bar` and is therefore not object safe:

```rust
trait Bar {}

trait Foo {
    fn foofunc<B: Bar>(&self, b: B); 
}
```

I want to make the trait `Foo` object safe. I gather the usual way to do this is to wrap it in a new, object-safe, trait (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412626/unable-to-create-a-polymorphic-type-because-the-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-obj)). Something along the lines of:

```rust
trait FooObjectSafe<B>
    where B: Bar,
{
    fn foofunc(&self, b: B);
}

impl<B, F> FooObjectSafe<B> for F
    where B: Bar,
          F: Foo,
{
    fn foofunc(&self, b: B) {
        Foo::foofunc(self, b)
    }
}
```

This seems very limiting however. If there is a function `use_foo` which takes a generic type implementing `Foo`, then it cannot be used with `FooObjectSafe` without changing its signature (I don't want to do this as in practise these functions come from different modules and are very divorced from one another):

```rust
struct BarImpl;
impl Bar for BarImpl {}

struct FooImpl;
impl Foo for FooImpl {
    fn foofunc<B: Bar>(&self, b: B) {}
}

fn main() {
    let foos = [
        Box::new(FooImpl{}) as Box<dyn FooObjectSafe<BarImpl>>,
        Box::new(FooImpl{})
    ];
    
    use_foo(foos[0]);
}
```

results in the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn FooObjectSafe<BarImpl>>: Foo` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:43:13
   |
43 |     use_foo(foos[0]);
   |     ------- ^^^^^^^ the trait `Foo` is not implemented for `Box<dyn FooObjectSafe<BarImpl>>`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `Foo` is implemented for `FooImpl`
note: required by a bound in `use_foo`
  --> src/main.rs:9:14
   |
8  | fn use_foo<F>(foo: F)
   |    ------- required by a bound in this
9  |     where F: Foo,
   |              ^^^ required by this bound in `use_foo`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Is there a better way to do this? I suspect I'm making some architectural faux pas here, but what exactly?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7c39cd9a27bcd0b9a2bc2a6322e3704)

Comment: That is basically the whole point of the [handshake patterns](https://without.boats/blog/handshake-patterns/). But there is no "best" solution for every case, so this question is too open ended.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger that resource is very helpful, could you post it in an answer so I could mark it as such?